# Global variables in R with counter

Tags: r, global-variables

I have a question in global variable and/or workflow of R. I have the following code.

```
counter <- 0
g <- function(){
f <- function(){
  counter <- counter + 1
  print(counter)
}
f()
f()
f()
}
g()
g()
g()
```

I was expecting to have the function g gives me 1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9. Instead, I got 1 1 1, 1 1 1, 1 1 1. Could someone help me figure out the reason? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We may need to do the assignment operator (`<<-`) to search through all the parent environment to make the assignment

```
g <- function(){
  f <- function(){
  counter <<- counter + 1
  print(counter)
 }
f()
f()
f()
}

g()
#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
g()
#[1] 4
#[1] 5
#[1] 6

g()
#[1] 7
#[1] 8
#[1] 9
```